# Android Arduino Bluetooth Led on/off

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I made a project Led on/offbut with 5 leds. I send strings to arduino bluetooth for on or off leds. But i need led on only some leds. For example i wont led on pin 10 and pin 9. But Before on pin 12 i can't on pin 11, and before off pin 12 i can't off another pins? Why? I put my code here:
For arduino:

```
while(Serial.available() > 0)
{
  command = ((byte)Serial.read());

  if(command == ':')
  {
    break;
  }

  else
  {
    string += command;
  }

  delay(1);
}
if(string == "A")
{
    ledOn();// ledOn(){analogWrite(led, 255); delay(10);}
}

if(string =="B")
{
    ledOff();
}
 if(string == "C")
{
    ledOnB();
}
if(string =="D")
{
    ledOffB();
}

 if(string == "E")
{
    ledOnC();
}

if(string =="F")
{
    ledOffC();
}

if(string =="G")
{
    ledOnD();
}

if(string =="H")
{
    ledOffD();
}
 if(string == "I")
{
    ledOnE();
}

if(string =="J")
{
    ledOffE();
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for setting the LEDs on and off?

Comment: I put a function like comment // ledOn(){analogWrite(led, 255); delay(10);} for all leds i have functions for on and off like ledOff(){analogWrite(led, 0); delay(10);}

Comment: Why are you using an ANALOG pin to drive a DIGITAL device such as a LED?

Comment: no matter what I use, analog or digitalWrite(). Result is the same.

Comment: Sincerely the bits of code you are showing don't tell me much. I made something similar and I can send commands to turn all the leds on or off, turn on  and off the single one and even send commands to make them run in sequence in both directions.